# Can Facebook authorize Web app and Native App

Tags: facebook

I don't understand Facebook App Config Advance.
With Authentication part: there are option which user can choose: Web or Native/Desktop.

Facebook said that "Only select native/Destop if you have embeded your app secret in your client app."
Does it means when I set it as Native/Desktop App, I can't authorize with web sdk?

Answer (score 0):

There is an API call to extend short lived token for a long lived one 
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=x&client_secret=x&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=x

I think that option enables this call but am not quite sure about this. 
Basically if you want to get long lived access token using only your desktop app (without implementing this call in server code) you should check this.